# What does the red 1! msg mean in the Byobu status panel?

Tags: homebrew

I've used [Byobu](http://byobu.org/index.html) on Linux systems, and the x! msg (x being a number) means that many corresponding packages need to be updated. However, on a Mac with brew (all packages updated) I cannot tell what the 1! msg is trying to tell me? Is there someway to parse it's data out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byobu checks for updates on macOS using [this script](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/f3a674a3036c609e89bae51960cc9892be611e5b/usr/lib/byobu/updates_available#L100-L111):

```sh
# Mac OSX
# check if any new versions have been installed since
# we last cached. this may not recognize formulae
# installed with HEAD
for f in $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/*; do
    [ "$f" -nt "$mycache" ] && return 0
done
# nothing new has been installed, so check wether the
# formulae database was updated
[ "$(brew --prefix)/Library/Formula" -nt "$mycache" ]
```

Comment: Good to know that is actually the number of brew package updates available. So, I guess something was cached somewhere... today the number went away.